# radiobutton list in coffeescript/angular issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am trying to display a radiobutton list in coffeescript like this:

```
  label(ng-repeat="p in priorities")
                    input(type="radio" ng-model="goal.priorityScore" value="p")
```

where priorities are:

```
  $scope.priorities=['Hi','Med','Lo']
```

However priorities displays a bunch of radio buttons but not with the prioritytext after each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code

```
 label(ng-repeat="p in priorities")
 input(type="radio" ng-model="goal.priorityScore" value="p")
```

To
    `label(ng-repeat="p in priorities")
 input(type="radio" ng-model="goal.priorityScore" value="{{p}}")`

Or

```
 label(ng-repeat="p in priorities")
 input(type="radio" ng-model="goal.priorityScore" value="{{p}}") {{p}}`
```

Hope it works